# Python Kmeans Print absolute frequency of words in each cluster

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, frequency, tf-idf

hello is there a way to print out the absolute frequencies of each word in a cluster?
My Code looks like this:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(list)

true_k = 4

model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)

model.fit(X)

print("Top terms per cluster:")

order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for i in range(true_k):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i,)
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :5]:
        print(' %s' % terms[ind],)
    print
```

My results are e.g.:

Top Terms per Cluster:

Cluster 0:

house

roof

table

chair

tv

Cluster 1:

...

But I want something like this, with absolute frequencies of each word:

Cluster 0:

house 65

roof 45

table 44

chair 33

tv 18

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by word frequency. The output of kmeans will be clustered sentences/documents i.e. `0:[doc1,doc2,doc3] 1:[doc4,doc5,doc6]...`. If you want top words in a cluster simply take the clustered docs together and refit a CountVectorizer on this group.

Comment: Im really bad with python :D How would you do what you said with code? And its one list

Comment: can you elaborate by what do you mean "one list" ? Even better update your question with the list you are passing to tfidfvectorizer.

Comment: The list contains all the words e.g. list =[("hello), ("house"), ("roof)...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is the need of tfidfvectorizer on words. But anyway using kmeans just predict on the cluster label for each word. And simply check word frequency in each cluster by doing a `df[df.cluster==#somelabel].words.value_counts`

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

words = ['this','is','a','very','long','text','my','name','is','not','cortana','today','I','will',
'write','a','long','text','I','am','from','planet','earth','this','text','does','not','make',
 'sense']

#tfidf
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(words)

#kmeans
true_k = 4
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)
lab = model.predict(X)

#save cluster labels for each sample in a dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame({'words':words, 'cluster':lab})

#check word freq for cluster==1
df[df.cluster==1].words.value_counts()
```